# Symfony 2.3 login form isn't authenticating

Tags: php, symfony, authentication

I'm trying to implement a rather basic login form with Symfony2.3, but I'm running into an error where I'm *sometimes* redirected to the expected page after providing correct credentials, but sometimes not (instead I'm just redirected back to the login page). Here is my `security.yml` file:

```
security:
    encoders:
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: plaintext
        Acme\MyBundle\Entity\User: sha512
    providers:
        main:
            id: acme.user.provider
    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        login_firewall:
            pattern: ^/login$
            security: false
        secured_area:
            pattern: ^/
            form_login: ~
            logout:
                path:   /logout
                target: /
    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login$, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, requires_channel: https }
        - { path: ^/, roles: ROLE_USER, requires_channel: https }
```

Here is my `SecurityController`:

```
<?php

namespace Acme\MyBundle\Controller;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Template;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContextInterface;

/**
 * Class SecurityController
 * @package Acme\MyBundle\Controller
 *
 * @Route("/")
 */
class SecurityController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @param Request $request
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
     *
     * @Route("/login", requirements={"_scheme" = "https"}, path="login")
     */
    public function LoginAction(Request $request)
    {
        $session = $request->getSession();

        // get the login error if there is one
        if ($request->attributes->has(SecurityContextInterface::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR)) {
            $error = $request->attributes->get(
                SecurityContextInterface::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR
            );
        } elseif (null !== $session && $session->has(SecurityContextInterface::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR)) {
            $error = $session->get(SecurityContextInterface::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
            $session->remove(SecurityContextInterface::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
        } else {
            $error = '';
        }

        // last username entered by the user
        $lastUsername = (null === $session) ? '' : $session->get(SecurityContextInterface::LAST_USERNAME);

        return $this->render(
            'AcmeMyBundle:Security:login.html.twig',
            array(
                // last username entered by the user
                'last_username' => $lastUsername,
                'error'         => $error,
            )
        );
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/login_check", requirements={"_scheme" = "https"}, path="login_check")
     */
    public function LoginCheckAction()
    {

    }

    /**
     * @Route("/logout", requirements={"_scheme" = "https"}, path="logout")
     */
    public function LogoutAction()
    {

    }
}
```

And here is my bundle's `routing.yml` file:

```
_security:
    resource: "@AcmeMyBundle/Controller/SecurityController.php"
    type: annotation
```

When I provide the proper credentials, I'm correctly logged in / redirected to the given URL about 20% of the time. The other 80% of the time I'm just redirected back to the form login page with no error message. I also don't see any error message when I try to login with incorrect credentials.

UPDATE: It looks like the issue is that Symfony is creating more than one session in my database on each request. I am using the pdo handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the issue was actually with the `Session` entity / table in which I was storing my session. I was using the [PDOSessionHandler](http://symfony.com/doc/2.3/cookbook/configuration/pdo_session_storage.html) to store sessions in the database, and had the following `$id` in my ORM `Session` entity:

```
<?php

namespace Acme\MyBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Session
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Session
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;
```

The `$id` should not have been of type integer, but (obviously (-_-) of type string. After changing the property to:

```
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
 * @ORM\Id
 */
private $id;
```

and running `php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force`, everything appears to be working correctly.

Answer (score 1):

get rid of your `login_firewall`, it is not needed since you have an access_control rule that allows anonymous access to your login page.  The less firewalls you have, the better.

I would suspect that the times you can't login, you are directly visiting your login page (/login), and therefore, attempting to login under your 'login_firewall', which is useless because it is only good for the /login page.  After you signin under your login_firewall, you are redirected to `/`, but you aren't authenticated under your 'secured_area' firewall (which is protecting `/`), so it asks you to sign in again, but this time under the correct firewall. I would assume that this time you are able to sign in.

This may be the issue, but regardless, get rid of your `login_firewall`

Comment: What you said about the two firewalls covering different domains makes sense, but I'm getting a redirect loop after removing the login_firewall. Also, I'm not sure that you're totally correct here because I don't want any anonymous users in my secured area. See http://symfony.com/doc/2.3/book/security.html#using-a-traditional-login-form and scroll down to avoiding common pitfalls #2.

Comment: Scratch that, I guess it's okay for anonymous users to visit the login page, just not the secured area, so it shouldn't matter because of the access control as you said. Adding `anonymous: ~` to the secured_area fixed the redirect problem, but not the login loop issue.

Comment: just for troubleshooting, can you remove the `requires_channel: https` from the access_control rules?  That could be the redirect issue, depending how your webserver is setup.

Comment: That is not the issue -- we are putting the correct headers in the packet so that Symfony's `isSecure()` method correctly returns true.